# trying to implement attendance in android using geofence with php

Tags: java, php, android, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm making an attendance system in android where employee should be able to put attendance only if he is in office premises through his mobile fingerprint scanner and I want to retrieve data like employee_name, location, date, time and save it in php I coded for geofencing but don't know how to proceed further below is code for geofencing
I searched all over the internet but didn't find a proper solution please anyone help me I really need this.....

**MyGeoFenCIN.java**

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Geofencing implements ResultCallback {

    // Constants
    public static final String TAG = Geofencing.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 1606; // 50 meters
    private static final long GEOFENCE_TIMEOUT = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 hours

    private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    private PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Context mContext;

    public Geofencing(Context context, GoogleApiClient client) {
        mContext = context;
        mGoogleApiClient = client;
        mGeofencePendingIntent = null;
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /***
     * Registers the list of Geofences specified in mGeofenceList with Google Place Services
     * Uses {@code #mGoogleApiClient} to connect to Google Place Services
     * Uses {@link #getGeofencingRequest} to get the list of Geofences to be registered
     * Uses {@link #getGeofencePendingIntent} to get the pending intent to launch the IntentService
     * when the Geofence is triggered
     * Triggers {@link #onResult} when the geofences have been registered successfully
     */
    public void registerAllGeofences() {
        // Check that the API client is connected and that the list has Geofences in it
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() ||
                mGeofenceList == null || mGeofenceList.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
            Log.e(TAG, securityException.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /***
     * Unregisters all the Geofences created by this app from Google Place Services
     * Uses {@code #mGoogleApiClient} to connect to Google Place Services
     * Uses {@link #getGeofencePendingIntent} to get the pending intent passed when
     * registering the Geofences in the first place
     * Triggers {@link #onResult} when the geofences have been unregistered successfully
     */
    public void unRegisterAllGeofences() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    // This is the same pending intent that was used in registerGeofences
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
            Log.e(TAG, securityException.getMessage());
        }
    }


    /***
     * Updates the local ArrayList of Geofences using data from the passed in list
     * Uses the Place ID defined by the API as the Geofence object Id
     *
     * @param places the PlaceBuffer result of the getPlaceById call
     */
    public void updateGeofencesList(PlaceBuffer places) {
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (places == null || places.getCount() == 0) return;
        for (Place place : places) {
            // Read the place information from the DB cursor
            String placeUID = place.getId();
            double placeLat = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            double placeLng = place.getLatLng().longitude;
            // Build a Geofence object
            Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(placeUID)
                    .setExpirationDuration(GEOFENCE_TIMEOUT)
                    .setCircularRegion(placeLat, placeLng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build();
            // Add it to the list
            mGeofenceList.add(geofence);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Creates a GeofencingRequest object using the mGeofenceList ArrayList of Geofences
     * Used by {@code #registerGeofences}
     *
     * @return the GeofencingRequest object
     */
    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }

    /***
     * Creates a PendingIntent object using the GeofenceTransitionsIntentService class
     * Used by {@code #registerGeofences}
     *
     * @return the PendingIntent object
     */
    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return mGeofencePendingIntent;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error adding/removing geofence : %s",
                result.getStatus().toString()));
    }

}
```

**GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java**

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Listener for geofence transition changes.
 *
 * Receives geofence transition events from Location Services in the form of an Intent containing
 * the transition type and geofence id(s) that triggered the transition. Creates a notification
 * as the output.
 */
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

    private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;
    String geofenceTransitionString;

    /**
     * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
     */
    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
        super(TAG);



    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents.
     * @param intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
     *               Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            //String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                   // geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            //Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences);

            mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(this, null);

            mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById(geofenceTransitionDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceBufferResponse> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        PlaceBufferResponse places = task.getResult();
                        Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + myPlace.getName());
                        CharSequence name = myPlace.getName();
                        String placeName = name.toString();
                        places.release();

                        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        String formattedDate = df.format(currentTime.getTime());

                        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionString + ": " + placeName + " " + formattedDate);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found.");
                    }
                }
            });
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, 

    geofenceTransition));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Gets transition details and returns them as a formatted string.
         *
         * @param geofenceTransition    The ID of the geofence transition.
         * @param triggeringGeofences   The geofence(s) triggered.
         * @return                      The transition details formatted as String.
         */
        private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                int geofenceTransition,
                List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

            geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);


            // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
            ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
                triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());


            }
            String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ",  triggeringGeofencesIdsList);



            return triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
        }

        /**
         * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
         * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
         */
        private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
            // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            // Construct a task stack.
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

            // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

            // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

            // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
            PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            // Define the notification settings.
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                    // to decode the Bitmap.
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setColor(Color.RED)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                    .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

            // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);

            // Get an instance of the Notification manager
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Issue the notification
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }

        /**
         * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
         *
         * @param transitionType    A transition type constant defined in Geofence
         * @return                  A String indicating the type of transition
         */
        private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
            switch (transitionType) {
                case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                    return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
                case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                    return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
                default:
                    return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
            }
        }
    }
```

So here I don't know how to make a condition that employee can put attendance only if he is in office premises and after attendance storing data in php I have seen apps on play store doing the same but I don't know how to do this

**MyPlaceAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.locationgeo.R;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;

public class PlaceListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceListAdapter.PlaceViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private PlaceBuffer mPlaces;


    public PlaceListAdapter(Context context, PlaceBuffer places) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mPlaces = places;
    }


    @Override
    public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Get the RecyclerView item layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_place_card, parent, false);
        return new PlaceViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlaceViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String placeName = mPlaces.get(position).getName().toString();
        String placeAddress = mPlaces.get(position).getAddress().toString();
        holder.nameTextView.setText(placeName);
        holder.addressTextView.setText(placeAddress);
    }

    public void swapPlaces(PlaceBuffer newPlaces){
        mPlaces = newPlaces;
        if (mPlaces != null) {
            // Force the RecyclerView to refresh
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mPlaces==null) return 0;
        return mPlaces.getCount();
    }

    /**
     * PlaceViewHolder class for the recycler view item
     */
    class PlaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView nameTextView;
        TextView addressTextView;

        public PlaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
            addressTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address_text_view);
        }

    }
}
```

**PlaceProvider.java**

```
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;


public class PlaceContentProvider extends ContentProvider {


    public static final int PLACES = 100;
    public static final int PLACE_WITH_ID = 101;

    // Declare a static variable for the Uri matcher that you construct
    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
    private static final String TAG = PlaceContentProvider.class.getName();

    // Define a static buildUriMatcher method that associates URI's with their int match
    public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        // Initialize a UriMatcher
        UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        // Add URI matches
        uriMatcher.addURI(PlaceContract.AUTHORITY, PlaceContract.PATH_PLACES, PLACES);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PlaceContract.AUTHORITY, PlaceContract.PATH_PLACES + "/#", PLACE_WITH_ID);
        return uriMatcher;
    }

    // Member variable for a PlaceDbHelper that's initialized in the onCreate() method
    private PlaceDbHelper mPlaceDbHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        mPlaceDbHelper = new PlaceDbHelper(context);
        return true;
    }

    /***
     * Handles requests to insert a single new row of data
     *
     * @param uri
     * @param values
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mPlaceDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Write URI matching code to identify the match for the places directory
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Uri returnUri; // URI to be returned
        switch (match) {
            case PLACES:
                // Insert new values into the database
                long id = db.insert(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                if (id > 0) {
                    returnUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
                } else {
                    throw new android.database.SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
                }
                break;
            // Default case throws an UnsupportedOperationException
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        // Notify the resolver if the uri has been changed, and return the newly inserted URI
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        // Return constructed uri (this points to the newly inserted row of data)
        return returnUri;
    }


    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        // Get access to underlying database (read-only for query)
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mPlaceDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Write URI match code and set a variable to return a Cursor
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Cursor retCursor;

        switch (match) {
            // Query for the places directory
            case PLACES:
                retCursor = db.query(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs,
                        null,
                        null,
                        sortOrder);
                break;
            // Default exception
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        // Set a notification URI on the Cursor and return that Cursor
        retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        // Return the desired Cursor
        return retCursor;
    }


    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        // Get access to the database and write URI matching code to recognize a single item
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mPlaceDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        // Keep track of the number of deleted places
        int placesDeleted; // starts as 0
        switch (match) {
            // Handle the single item case, recognized by the ID included in the URI path
            case PLACE_WITH_ID:
                // Get the place ID from the URI path
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                // Use selections/selectionArgs to filter for this ID
                placesDeleted = db.delete(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{id});
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
        // Notify the resolver of a change and return the number of items deleted
        if (placesDeleted != 0) {
            // A place (or more) was deleted, set notification
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }
        // Return the number of places deleted
        return placesDeleted;
    }


    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {
        // Get access to underlying database
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mPlaceDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        // Keep track of the number of updated places
        int placesUpdated;

        switch (match) {
            case PLACE_WITH_ID:
                // Get the place ID from the URI path
                String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
                // Use selections/selectionArgs to filter for this ID
                placesUpdated = db.update(PlaceContract.PlaceEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=?", new String[]{id});
                break;
            // Default exception
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }

        // Notify the resolver of a change and return the number of items updated
        if (placesUpdated != 0) {
            // A place (or more) was updated, set notification
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }
        // Return the number of places deleted
        return placesUpdated;
    }


    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't say what problem you are having.  What was your desired/expected system and how is this falling short of that?

Comment: Are you dealing with one known present location, or many unknown future locations?

Comment: This just looks like example code from someplace.

Comment: Hello actually i followed a tutorial for geofencing that is why it is looking like example code i want to make employee attendance using geofence with punchin punchout and save the data in php and i have basic knowledge of volley as well but i dont know how to save geofence data in php please help me

Comment: I'm dealing with just one location that is my office and i want that i should be able to punchin or punchout only if i'm at office premises i tried to search extensively for this but nothing worked if you can help me please let me know

Comment: why are you deciding to use geofencing and not just upload the location (latitude and longitude)?

Comment: Please tell me how can i   achieve that without geofencing because i dont have much idea about location saving in android using php and second thing is can i store biometric in php for punchin punch out please of you know please help me any tutorial any link i searched but couldnt find any.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to make an app that employees would use to clock in/out by:

A) scanning their fingerprint (with the app),

and B) clicking a button "IN" or "OUT" (with the same app) ??

If so, then you don't need geofencing.  Geofencing is for situations where you want something to happen *automatically* when a user enters a designated area.

Your situation, on the other hand, only requires that your app be [aware of the phone's location](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location) when the user clicks IN/OUT.

When the user clicks IN/OUT, you would just upload the latitude and longitude, time, ID etc. and the server would determine whether the latitude or longitude is within the boundary (you can do that like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929834/how-to-restrict-app-usability-to-a-certain-geographical-area-android)).

If they are not in the boundary, then the server would return an error... or it could be quiet about it.

You will also have to guard against [fake locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803398/detecting-mock-location-not-working-android).

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but how do fetch the id name date time location and save it in php datbase because i'm working on php and you are also right about mock location how do i achieve this i want to learn more about this..

Comment: I've helped all I can... this is a big project you are embarking on.  The problem requires thoughtful design, not a quick coding solution.

Comment: I really need help please if you could help me i have been trying from last two weeks but couldnt find a solution is there a way i can get proper coding of similar apps on playstore i tried decompiling with apktool but that doesnt provide proper code i'm really stuck at this point....

Comment: You need to design your own solution.  Break your problem into smaller parts and write more (clear) questions on stackoverflow... it's unlikely that anyone is just going to write your entire app for you, both server and client side.  Just start with a simple example program that displays realtime latitude and longitude on the screen and go from there.